# Determining the result of Boolean shape operations on closed Bézier shapes

Tags: geometry, boolean-algebra, bezier-curve

Given two closed shapes made up of Bézier curves (and/or straight lines), I'm looking for an efficient way of calculating the resulting shape of the following Boolean operations:

- union
- difference
- intersection
- slice (imagine each of the shapes in the Venn diagram as its own shape; this operation is optional and can be expressed as a composite operation of the above)

To give this problem some context, I'm trying to implement Boolean operations for SVG shapes using Javascript processing; defining paths in SVG only gives you [fill rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983256/how-can-i-cut-one-shape-from-another) and [clipping paths](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#EstablishingANewClippingPath), but none of these helps with creating arbitrary boolean-derived shapes.

*Addendum:* I'm also looking for a way to determine if a point lies inside a closed Bézier shape.

*Addendum 2:* [I found a page](http://processingjs.nihongoresources.com/bezierinfo/) that explains such concepts, but is missing the chapter on boolean operations; there is a placeholder example in ProcessingJS demonstrating boolean operations, but as far as I can tell, it uses rasterizing to determine the inside/outside state of a point.

Comment: since I noticed some people following the bezierinfo link: I recently fully redid the article, and it now contains examples and code for performing boolean shape operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To perform those Boolean operations, you must be able find the intersections between two Bézier curves.  This is a difficult problem. To gain some appreciation, look at [this web page](http://www.truetex.com/bezint.htm) on the topic by Richard Kinch.  If you are using the usual cubic Bézier curves, then you are seeking the intersection between two cubics, which, by [Bézout's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem),
requires finding the roots of a 9th-degree polynomial if done numerically, and a deep recursion if done by divide and conquer.  This is why sometimes the
computation is avoided ("rasterizing," as you say).

Here is a useful description of this topic, written by Tom Sederberg of BYU: [PDF link](http://tom.cs.byu.edu/~557/text/ch7.pdf).  See Section 7.4, "Computing the Intersection of Two Bézier Curves."

Comment: I meant _rasterizing_ in my question above to mean rendering the actual shapes onto a bitmap buffer to map pixels as the inside/outside of a given shape. As for the intersections, the link above states that a simplification is to use line segment approximations to find the approximate `t` and split the Bezier using De Castelau's algorithm; I'm just looking for something that can be applied in a reasonable run time.

Comment: "intersection between two cubics...requires finding the roots of a 6th-degree polynomial" Are you sure it's not 9th degree? For cubics, I think Bezout says that it's 3rd degree times 3rd degree.